Why my 2015 Nissan Altima won’t start? The battery,alternator and starter is good
After 2 months of having my car it wouldn’t start one morning I got a new battery new terminals still the same thing but it starts when I get a jump I thought it could be my ac switch got that changed and it stopped doing that for about a week and it started doing it again so I got new spark plugs it was fine now it won’t start again it seems like the cold weather is playing a part in it at first the jump will last all day and the next morning my car won’t start since it’s getting cold I can jump it in the morning and a few hours of sitting it won’t start again…. Idk what’s going on with it …. I got my starter and alternator checked they said it’s good no problems any ideas what can be wrong?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the voltage at the battery, with and without it running?
